# Fix the position of overlapped grid item

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

Recently working on a website with a pretty simple layout, a grid container with 5 grid items, a main grid item with nested grid inside to display text(each of them take height 100vh), with other 4 overlap on top of it in order to have 4 dashed line. **However I wanna keep the 4 overlapped div aside even when I am scrolling the main grid item.**

Here is the code

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 2.5;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
body .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
body .section {
  grid-area: 1/1/7/6;
  height: 400vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2740, #12355A, #224A73, #4985C1);
}
body .section .sub-section {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}
body .section .sub-section .words {
  place-self: center;
}
body .top-left {
  grid-area: 1/1/4/3;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
}
body .top-left .deco-line {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 250px;
}
body .top-right {
  grid-area: 1/4/4/6;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}
body .top-right .deco-line {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 200px;
}
body .bottom-left {
  grid-area: 4/1/7/3;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: end;
}
body .bottom-left .deco-line {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 250px;
}
body .bottom-right {
  grid-area: 4/4/7/6;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: center;
}
body .bottom-right .deco-line {
  border: 3px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="sub-section">
      <div class="words">
        <p>This is a sentence.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section">
      <div class="words">
        <p>This is a sentence.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section">
      <div class="words">
        <p>This is a sentence.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-section">
      <div class="words">
        <p>This is a sentence.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-left">
    <hr class="deco-line">
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    <hr class="deco-line">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-left">
    <hr class="deco-line">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-right">
    <hr class="deco-line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen link for a better demonstrate
https://codepen.io/cheersxx/pen/OJgPQwZ

I tried to set the whole page as overflow hidden then set overflow-y scroll to the section div but it is not working

Any help will be appreciate..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry for the inconvenience, I just edited the question.

Comment: If you don't want those elements to scroll you would need to use `position:fixed` but I don't think you will get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @Paulie_D I just tried it and the grid item disappeared, it is so frustrating..